# Tried the monad pattern but still have repetitive error handling

Tags: go

I read [Rob Pike's post](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values) but it only works for repetitive loops. I, on the other hand, have this. Notice how I added the `err` field, accessible via the `Error()` method, in a futile attempt to reduce the if errs.

The code above is simpler, but the ReadRLP() function is no different from just returning a err. Is there some pattern that can help with this?

```
type namePreclaimRLP struct {
    ObjectTag         uint
    RlpMessageVersion uint
    AccountID         []uint8
    AccountNonce      uint64
    CommitmentID      []uint8
    Fee               big.Int
    TTL               uint64
    err               error
}

func (n *namePreclaimRLP) ReadRLP(s *rlp.Stream) (aID, cID string) {
    blob, err := s.Raw()
    if err != nil {
        n.err = err
    }
    err = rlp.DecodeBytes(blob, n)
    if err != nil {
        n.err = err
    }
    _, aID, err = readIDTag(n.AccountID)
    if err != nil {
        n.err = err
    }
    _, cID, err = readIDTag(n.CommitmentID)
    if err != nil {
        n.err = err
    }
    return aID, cID
}

func (n *namePreclaimRLP) Error() (err error) {
    return n.err
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile as written (there are a lot of missing types), so I can't fully test this code, but I would expect something along these lines, returning `err` in the typical Go approach, rather than making it part of another type, which is unusual and a bit confusing:

```
func (n *namePreclaimRLP) ReadRLP(s *rlp.Stream) (aID, cID string, err error) {
    var blob SomeType // Depends on what blob actually is
    if blob, err = s.Raw(); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if err = rlp.DecodeBytes(blob, n); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if _, aID, err = readIDTag(n.AccountID); err != nil {
        return
    }

    _, cID, err = readIDTag(n.CommitmentID)

    return
}
```

I'd delete your `Error()` function here and the `err` field. `namePreclaimRLP` is not a kind of error. It feels you're abusing the interface there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to reduce the amount of code and retain an more idiomatic API by returning an error.

```
func (n *namePreclaimRLP) ReadRLP(s *rlp.Stream) (aID, cID string, err error) {
    se := func(e error) {
       if e != nil {
          err = e
       }
    }

    blob, e := s.Raw()
    se(e)
    se(rlp.DecodeBytes(blob, n))
    _, aID, e = readIDTag(n.AccountID)
    se(e)
    _, cID, e = readIDTag(n.CommitmentID)
    se(e)
    return
}
```

Comment: Both answers were good but I chose this one because the use of a closure here over the err variable was pretty smart

Comment: Just noticed something: if the first statement returns a non-nil error, execution is not terminated, and the second statement will be executed with invalid input. Which will then result in an err, which will then overwrite the first, original err.

Comment: @randomshinichi  For what it's worth, the code in the question has the same flaw.